# Google Analytics - How can I cache GA? for Page Speed Insights 100/100

Tags: google-analytics, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

How can I achieve a 100/100 page speed insight score? I tried to exclude scripts if the user agent is speed insights bot but it doesn't work in my case score is still the same.
I'm using PHP laravel framework.

```
<?php if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Speed Insights') === false): ?>
// your analytics code here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to host GA script locally. But you will be forced to care about updates on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your GA script locally. The result will be better but you will have to check for update often.

The other good solution is to async your script and preconnect to analytics.
You can preconnect to GA with :

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="//www.google-analytics.com" crossorigin="anonymous"> <!-- as soon as you can -->

<!-- then -->
<script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

I use it on my website : [36 Pixels](https://www.36pixels.fr/) and the Google PageSpeed Insights is good with GA : [GPS test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=fr&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.36pixels.fr%2F&tab=mobile)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flying Analytics](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flying-analytics/) to self-host Google Analytics (or even use Minimal Analytics)

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 Page Speed Insights user agents are: "Chrome-Lighthouse" for mobile and "Google Page Speed Insights" for desktop. So, the php code will be like this:

```
<?php if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome-Lighthouse') === false  || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Google Page Speed Insights') === false): ?>
// your google analytics code and other external script you want to hide from PageSpeed Insights here
<?php endif; ?>
```